# Is it possible to have a non static method as a parameter

Tags: java

```
public static String answer(vector alpha, vector beta){
    return (alpha.additionVector(beta)).vectortoString();
}
```

I want to apply this method to other operations. However, the other operators include dot product cross product etc.. So instead of limiting this method into only adding vectors, I would like this method to apply dot product or cross product. the parameter will effect the additionVector and potentially replace it depending on the parameters given.

I'm not exactly sure where to start as I tried putting the output of the non static method as one of the parameter.

```
public static String answer(vector alpha, vector beta, vector operator){
    return (alpha.operator(beta)).vectortoString();
}
```

But then it assumes that `operator()` is a function rather than a parameter.

Edit: let me try to rephrase the question.

I have a method called `crossProduct()` that returns the cross product of two vectors.

I have another method called `subtraction()` that returns the subtraction between two vectors.

What I want to do is this:

```
public String answer(vector alpha, vector beta, x){
     //where x is the non static method for the vector class and takes in a vector
     return (alpha.x(b)).vectortoString();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all

Comment: you mean to say all kind of vector operation should be performed by given method?

Comment: Please add the code for your `vector` class. We need that to be able to answer your question. Once you have done that, post a comment here so that we know to take a look again and help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html). [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) may be a good fit for your specific use case:

```
public static String answer(Vector alpha, Vector beta, BinaryOperator<Vector> operator){
    return operator.apply(alpha, beta).toString();
}
```

Assuming that the `Vector` class has a bunch of methods like the ones bellow:

```
public Vector add(Vector other) { // ...
}

public Vector subtract(Vector other) { //...
}
```

You can pass them around as method references:

```
String firstAnswer = answer(alpha, beta, Vector::add);
String secondAnswer = answer(alpha, beta, Vector::subtract);
```

PS: My code is following usual Java coding conventions. E.g., Class names use PascalCase and methods use camelCase. I highly suggest adopting the same conventions when writing Java code.

Comment: thanks a lot, using functional interfaces helped solve my problem.